# Comparable with doubles

Tags: java, comparable

Suppose that a class Point2D has been defined for storing a 2-dimensional point with x and y coordinates (both as doubles). The class includes the following members:

[image]

Your task is to modify the class to be Comparable by adding an appropriate compareTo method. Points should be compared relative to their distance from the origin, with points closer to the origin considered "less" than points farther from it. The distance between two points is defined as the square root of the sum of the squares of the differences between the x and y coordinates.

I'm unsure on how to implement the compareTo method when there are double. 
With integers and strings I would use the following syntax:

```
public int compareTo(object name) {
    // comparing integers
    if (this.object != other.object) {
        return this.field - other.field;
    } else { // comparing strings
        return toString().compareTo(other.toString());
    }
}
```

Is there a generalized implementation strategy when comparing between two doubles, like currency or the Point class above?

Comment: So `5, 0` and `0, 5` are "equal" as far as `compareTo()` is concerned, huh? Guess javadoc of `Point.compareTo()` should say *"Note: this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals."*, as recommended in the javadoc of [`Comparable.compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`int Double.compare(double d1, double d2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29).

You also should not do `this.field - other.field`, since that may return incorrect result in case of numeric overflow. Use [`int Integer.compare(int x, int y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29).